# Why javascript not run line by line

Tags: javascript, synchronization

Below are html/javascript code, but when call function calc(), its output a `<ol>`
 tag first, but bot run script orderly.
I have remove the `settimeout()` function to make it running sync.

Can some one give explain will be appreciated.

```js
function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
regex_field = $('regx');
content = $('content');
output = $('output');
flag_field = $('flag')


flag_field.addEventListener('input', function() {
  calc();
});
content.addEventListener('input', function() {
  calc();
});
regex_field.addEventListener('input', function() {
  calc();
});

function calc() {
  //setTimeout(function () {
  var re = new RegExp(regex_field.value, flag_field.value)
  console.log(re);
  found = content.value.match(re);
  if (found) {
    $('output').innerHTML = "<ol>";
    for (let i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
      $('output').innerHTML += '<li>' + found[i] + '</li>';
    }
    $('output').innerHTML += "</ol>";
  } else {
    $('output').innerHTML = "Nothing Found!";
  }
  // }, 500);

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-inline">
      RegExp
      <input class="col-sm-4 form-control form-control-sm" type="text" id="regx" placeholder="Regex Input"> Flag
      <input class="col-sm-1 form-control form-control-sm" type="text" id="flag">
      <br>
      <div>
        <p>Input Content</p>
        <textarea class="form-control col-sm-12" name="input" placeholder="Text" id="content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>Content get</p>
      <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Output is like below. I don't understand why 'ol' tage go above the 'li' tag.

```
<div id="output">
  <ol></ol> //  <---  question here
  <li>12</li>
  <li>34</li>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 3):

When you do `$('output').innerHTML = "<ol>";` it immediately adds the `ol` tag to `#output`.  Since an `<ol>` without a closing `</ol>` is invalid, the DOM automatically closes it. So you get:

```
<div id="output">
    <ol></ol>
</div>
```

Then, you do `$('output').innerHTML += '<li>' + found[i] + '</li>';`, so it adds that line to `#output` (which is also invalid, since an `li` can't belong to a `div`, but it doesn't know how to fix it):

```
<div id="output">
    <ol></ol>
    <li>12</li>
</div>
```

What you want to do it build up the innerHTML, then set it all at once, so more like:

```
if (found) {
    var output = '';
    output = "<ol>";
    for (let i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
       output += '<li>' + found[i] + '</li>';
    }
    output += "</ol>";
} else {
    output = "Nothing Found!";
}
$('output').innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: You beat me to it. But that's probably because I started by looking for a dupe. There must be hundreds like this, but searching for "assign innerHTML" finds too many non-dupes.

Comment: I should really be better about looking for dupes first.

Comment: I'll save this in my dupe list.